# Storing GMP mpf_t and an mpz_t types in a file

Tags: c, file, gmp, storing-data

How do I save GMP objects of type mpf_t or mpz_t in a file in C ?
Or how can I access the blocks of allocated memory for these types so that I can write them directly to a file ?

#### Edit

```
fwrite(&gmp_obj->_mp_size, sizeof(long), 1, fout);
fwrite(&gmp_obj->_mp_prec, sizeof(long), 1, fout);
fwrite(&gmp_obj->_mp_exp, sizeof(long), 1, fout);
fwrite(gmp_obj->_mp_d, sizeof(long), gmp_obj->_mp_size, fout);
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use GMP's I/O functions. For [`mpf_t`](http://gmplib.org/manual/I_002fO-of-Floats.html#I_002fO-of-Floats) :

> — Function: `size_t mpf_out_str (FILE *stream, int base, size_t n_digits, mpf_t op)`
>   — Function: `size_t mpf_inp_str (mpf_t rop, FILE *stream, int base)`

For [`mpz_t`](http://gmplib.org/manual/I_002fO-of-Integers.html#I_002fO-of-Integers):

> — Function: `size_t mpz_out_str (FILE *stream, int base, mpz_t op)`
>   — Function: `size_t mpz_inp_str (mpz_t rop, FILE *stream, int base)`
>   — Function: `size_t mpz_out_raw (FILE *stream, mpz_t op)`
>   — Function: `size_t mpz_inp_raw (mpz_t rop, FILE *stream)`

In addition to `*_raw`, there are binary import/export functions for `mpz_t` that are described in a [separate section](http://gmplib.org/manual/Integer-Import-and-Export.html#Integer-Import-and-Export))

> — Function: `void mpz_import (mpz_t rop, size_t count, int order, size_t size, int endian, size_t nails, const void *op)`
>   — Function: `void * mpz_export (void *rop, size_t *countp, int order, size_t size, int endian, size_t nails, mpz_t op)`